# Angular Material dialog: is there a way not to use the data property as "data.*" in the template?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I have a template like the one below:

**card.component.html**

```
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
  <img mat-card-image src="{{ item.media_url }}" />
  <mat-card-content class="custom">
    <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

It is a Material Card used inside a parent View that creates a grid with cards, each having a specific `item.media_url` and `item.caption`

[image: card grid]

**events.component.ts**

```
<div class="content">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
    <div
      fxFlex="25%"
      fxFlex.md="33%"
      fxFlex.sm="50%"
      fxFlex.xs="100%"
      *ngFor="let item of events"
    >
      <app-card  [item]="item" #myCard></app-card>
      <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(myCard)">SCOPRI DI PIU'</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, inside the `ngFor` loop, below each card, there's a button that is supposed to open a dialog showing only one card at a time (the one above the clicked button in the grid).

I would like to put very the same card with its `item.media_url` and `item.caption` in this dialog, so I thought to use [the `data` property of MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MAT_DIALOG_DATA) to do this.

**card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() item : any;
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**events.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsService } from '../../shared/services/events.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CardComponent } from 'src/app/shared/card/card.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.css'],
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any[];

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEvents();
  }

  getEvents(): void {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.events = response.data;
      console.log(this.events);
    });
  }

  openDialog(card: any) {
    this.dialog.open(CardComponent, {
      data: {
        item: card,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

However, when I do this, I need to pass `data` to `this.dialog.open()`, not `item`, nor `card`.

Right now I am getting the error `ERROR TypeError: ctx.item is undefined` (which I perfectly understand why I am getting).

Is there a way I can somehow "alias" `data` as `item`, or maybe a better way to do this?

Comment: `openDialog(myCard)` is getting as param a template reference?

Comment: I am not sure. I am passing it by defining an id inside the `ngFor` loop (`#myCard`), but I don't know if this makes it a TemplateRef. I know that `this.dialog.open()` should accept both a template or a component though...

Comment: Yes, it accepts both Component and TemplateRef but only as first param. [src](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/21bb4d5a6a60b9f5883121341295506db77a1154/src/material/dialog/dialog.ts#L139)

Comment: I think (hopefully) it is what I am doing ;)

Comment: can you `console.log(card)` in your `openDialog` method? what is the output?

Comment: sure! it's `Object { data: null, __ngContext__: (61) […], item: {…} }
events.component.ts:28:12` (if you need more, I would add more, thanks for your time!)

Comment: is the property `item: {...}` contains what you looking for?

Comment: well, it is actually an Object with all the things I need. The problem is that I can't pass it to MatDialog so easily: MatDialog `open` method has a property called `data` which I can use to define my data (`item` in my case), but then the template of the card should have `data` instead of `item` to use it. I cannot override `item` with `data` in my card component as it is already defined as `@Input` and works to build the grid from within the Parent's component `ngFor`. I should probably try another route. I just need a button to display the card itself in a dialog, but it seems tricky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234988/discussion-between-robert-and-umbe1987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work we did the following:

```
  openDialog(card: CardComponent) { <-- strongly type
    console.log(card.item); <-- access item
    this.dialog.open(CardComponent, {
      data: {
        item: card.item <-- pass it as param
      }
    });
  }
```

next in `card.component.ts` set the 'item` property.

```
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    if (data) { <-- only if data is injected
      this.item = data.item; <-- set item
    }
  }
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adiccn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fevents%2Fevents.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you again Robert. It's been tough!

Answer (score 1):

Robert's coment under your question answers the template / component part.
As for the data alias question, the answer is no. `data` is a property of the `MatDialogConfig` class, as shown [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/21bb4d5a6a60b9f5883121341295506db77a1154/src/material/dialog/dialog-config.ts#L84) and to the best of my knowledge, you can't change it.